# Cause a Cap Deploy error to fail a Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, capistrano

So I'm working on a jenkins build and I'm doing a

```
cap deploy
```

in the execute shell section. What I'd like the build to do is to fail if Cap spits out any errors. For example, I just got this one:

```
fatal: write error: No space left on device
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

I tried to do something like this

```
cap -v deploy > deploylog
```

and then grepping it for errors, but it didn't write out anything to the deploy log.

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to jenkins, so if this isn't enough information let me know and I can add more :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected the cap command to exit with a non-zero value if it encounters an error, which should make the shell step in Jenkins fail.

You can get around this by using the [Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) to search for errors in the console output.